# Pandas: Memory Error when setting dataframe to_panel

Tags: python, pandas, panel, pivot-table, transpose

I have the following [df](https://github.com/108michael/ms_thesis/blob/master/crsp.dime.mpl.df) in pandas:

```
iu.head(2)
  indx  cycle   feccandid   recipient.cfscore.dyn   recipient.cfscore   num.givers.total    total.indiv.contrib     total.pac.contribs  pacid       date        catcode     type    di  cid        amount   contributor_cfscore     disposition     bills
0   0   2008    H4OK02089   0.275                   0.313               1831                  1189145                    508082        C00253153    2007-12-31  G2900       24K     D   N00026481   5000    0.840                   support           1
1   1   2008    H4OK02089   0.275                   0.313               1831                  1189145                    508082        C00003764    2007-12-31  G2900       24K     D   N00026481   6500    0.658                   support           1
```

I am trying to set it up for sending into panel data. I would like to have `feccandid` as `items`. I would like the `major_axis` to be `date` and the `minor_axis` to be all of the columns. I have tried the following:

```
mm=iu.pivot_table(index=['date', 'indx', 'cycle', 'recipient.cfscore.dyn', 'recipient.cfscore', \
'num.givers.total', 'catcode', 'feccandid']).unstack('feccandid')
```

Then I reset the index: `mm=mm.reset_index()`

Set index again: `mm=mm.set_index(['date', 'indx'])`
and then try to send to panel: `mm.to_panel()`

But then I get a `MemoryError`
Does anyone have any ideas on this?